# How to select an element with a chain of ids in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">...</div>
</div>
```

In Prototpye I could just use that code to select the inner div by id:

```
$('#outer #inner');
```

How would I do that in jQuery? I tried the same selector, but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: That can't possibly not work. Something else is wrong. Might there be a conflict between libraries?

Comment: since you are having the id there is no need to use a relative selector you can just do `$('#inner')` - ID of an element must be unique in a document

Comment: @ArunPJohny the same JavaScript file may be included on multiple pages with `#inner` used for different purposes. You shouldn't assume that `#inner` will always be contained within `#outer`.

Comment: Assuming your JS runs after the elements have been parsed (i.e., your JS is in a script block that appears after the elements in question, or you are using a document ready or onload handler), your selector `$("#outer #inner")` will definitely work as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4MEU5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#outer #inner');
```

Is already valid in jQuery and would select the `#inner` descendant of `#outer`.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/SeVvH/1/).

You could also use:

```
$('#outer > #inner');
$('#outer').find('#inner');
$('#outer').children('#inner');
```

Comment: That's simply the correct answer :) I honestly didn't even try the selector that was in the question, in retrospect I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.